# How do I process non-real time data in batches in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am new Big data and Spark. I have to work on real-time data and old data from the past 2 years. There are around a million rows for each day. I am using PySpark and Databricks. Data is partitioned on created date. I have to perform some transformations and load it to a database.

For real-time data, I will be using spark streaming (readStream to read, perform transformation and then writeStream).
How do I work with the data from the past 2 years? I tried filtering data from 30 days I got good throughput. Should I be running the process on all 2 years of data at once or should I doing it in batches? If I perform this processes in batches, does Spark provide a way to batch it or do I do it in Python. Also, do I run these batches in parallel or in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of open ended but let me try to address your concerns.

> How do I work with the data from the past 2 years? I tried filtering data from 30 days I got good throughput. Should I be running the process on all 2 years of data at once or should I doing it in batches?

Since you are new to Spark, do it in batches and start by running 1 day at a time, then 1 week and so one. Get your program to run successfully and optimize. As you increase the batch size you can increase your cluster size using Pyspark Dataframes (not Pandas). If your job is verified and efficient, you can run monthly, bi-monthly or larger batches (smaller jobs are better in your case).

> If I perform this processes in batches, does Spark provide a way to batch it or do I do it in Python. Also, do I run these batches in parallel or in sequence?

You can use the date range as parameters to your Databricks job and use data bricks to schedule your jobs to ran back to back. Sure you can run them in parallel on different clusters but the whole idea with Spark is to use Sparks distributed capability and run your job on as many worker nodes as your job requires. Again, get one small job to work and validate your results, then validate a larger set and so on. If you feel confident, start a large cluster (many and fat workers) and run a large date range.
It is not an easy task for a newbie but should be a lot of fun. Best wishes.